# Removing a circle in d3 with a specific cx and cy values?

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to remove a circle element in d3 with a specific cx and cy value. I am aware of the .remove() method but I was wondering if I could remove only a specific circle element based on its dimensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Select all](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_selectAll) the circle elements on the page:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
```

From those, use [filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) to select only the circles you want to remove:

```
  .filter(function(d){ 
     return this.attributes.cx == removeCX && this.attributes.cy == removeCY; })
```

Use [remove](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-remove) to get rid of them:

```
  .remove()
```

That said, I can't think of very many situations where you'd want to use the circle's actual position in the SVG to get rid of it; using d3, you'd probably be better off operating on the data bound to the circle instead.